# Citing in URL in latex

Tags: latex, pdflatex, texmaker

I am trying to write my bachelor's thesis in latex but I'm struggling with the URL in the literature. 
I use Citavi and converted it to a bib file. However, when inserting in latex, the URL citation doesn't look properly.

My prerequisites are: 
Windows 10 Pro
Texmaker 5.0.2 
Citavi 6.0.0.2

This is what my compiled file looks like:

Literatur
(2017): "Deforestation and Forest Degradation," .

That is what I'd need:

International Union for Conservation of Nature (Hg.) (2017): Deforestation and Forest Degradation (Issues Brief). URL: https://www.iucn.org/sites/dev/files/deforestation-forest_degradation_issues_brief_final.pdf, zuletzt geprüft am 07.07.2018.

My Bib file, generated from Citavi, looks like this:

```
% This file was created with Citavi 6.0.0.2

@misc{InternationalUnionforConservationofNature.2017,
editor = {{International Union for Conservation of Nature}},
year = {2017},
title = {Deforestation and Forest Degradation},
url = {\url   {https://www.iucn.org/sites/dev/files/deforestation-forest_degradation_issues_brief_final.pdf}},
urldate = {07.07.2018},
series = {Issues Brief}
}
```

and that is my current tex file. I've removed text and sections for clearity. But I've used all packages as in the original file.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[left=4cm, right=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\sloppy

\begin{document}
\cite{InternationalUnionforConservationofNature.2017}
\section{Literaturverzeichnis}
\bibliography{Literatur1.2}
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for your help - I'am a totally newbee and therefore thankful for every advice. Even if it's a different approach to citing properly.

Comment: You should probably ask this on the [TeX - LaTeX stack exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: thanks for your advice. I'm going to ask the question on the recommended forum. but i will let this one open.

Comment: the question has been answered in this forum: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446490/citing-url-in-latex/446569#446569

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's already been answered on [tex.se].